# Network check from options menu in Android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I know that onCreateOptionsMenu is only called once on an activity, but is it possible to set a network check on onOptionsItemSelected?

I have tried using ConnectivityManager network checks when an item is selected, but it always returns true... I'm not sure if it is set when the onCreateOptionsMenu is called and then locking in the network state.

Here is my code:

```
public void refreshCheck(){

try
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(cm == null)
        isAvailable = false;
    else
        isAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable();
}
catch(Exception e){}

if(isAvailable == true)
{   

    listDataPopulate();    

}
else
{
    Toast refresherror = Toast.makeText(this, "Connection interrupted. Unable to refresh.", duration);
    refresherror.show();    
}       

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.news_menu, menu);
return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

switch(item.getItemId())
{
case R.id.aboutMenuItem:
AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("About App").setMessage("About this app....").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
break;
case R.id.refreshNewsMenuItem:

    refreshCheck();

break;
default:
}
{

}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Why not do the check in onCreate?

Comment: The code looks fine, it *shouldn't* get set in onCreateOptionsMenu as long as the cm is declared in that external function. However, have you tested for sure that it returns true even if the network is disconnected when onCreateOptionsMenu is called?

Comment: @Cruceo I know that onCreate only gets called once, so if they load this rss feed successfully, it will always say it's online. I want to check if they are still online before attempting to refresh the feed. As it is, it crashes the app because if I go offline it still tries to fetch data.

Comment: @matt5784 If I place this anywhere else on that activity other than in the options menu, it successfully determines online/offline status. Within that menu, it always calls listDataPopulate, even after I exit the application with the home key, change settings to offline, and go back into the application and attempt refresh.

Comment: you mean if you place the `refreshCheck();` call anywhere else in the activity it works properly? Or if you place the code from that method elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, have you tried combining your if blocks? e.g. if (cm == null){ isAvailable = false;  Toast.show(); } else { isAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable();  listDataPopulate();  } I only ask because it may be possible the cm call throwing an error, no? I realize the combined version isn't very nice but it may be useful for debugging

Comment: @matt5784 I combined the blocks and at first nothing happened (No reaction, but ALSO no crashing). When I moved the toast message into the catch block it was received. Trying to figure out the cause, but this is much better than a crash.

Comment: @EvanDyson why not put the check before trying to access the feed?

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is perhaps the context for the getSystemService is wrong? (I assume that is the line throwing an exception?) Other that that I don't know, I just tried similar code and it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your logic checking (and the reaction to what you find) inside of [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) instead.

That method gets called each time the options menu is opened, instead of just the first time. This way it will check each time the user opens the options whether or not it has connection, and thus should show the refresh option.